# I am trying to set an index in an array to null and it works until the method finishes and it reverts back to what it was before

Tags: java

This is the method. It's telling me its setting the value to null within the method and it is as I've checked. But after the method has finished the value reverts to what it was before I set it to null. Help would be appreciated greatly.

```
public void deleteStudent(String studentName) {
    //deletes a Student object by going through the array and checking for an student name the same as the entered name.
    boolean deleteCheck = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length; i += 1) {
        if (studentList[i] != null) {
            Student a = this.studentList[i];
            if (a.getName().equals(studentName)) {
                studentList[i] = null;
                deleteCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //deleteCheck is used to print a message if no student was deleted.
    if(!deleteCheck){
        System.out.println("There is no student on this course called " + studentName + ".");
    } else System.out.println("Student deleted.");
}
```

Comment: Show the code that calls this method. It suspect that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Bohemian I really don't understand why my answer was deleted as "not answering the question". 1) I gave hint to improve his code. 2) I've mentionned that the code he gave us did not revert the values of the array and that the problem was somewhere else, or a mis-understanding of his part where printing the array would have helped him understand. But anyway, can't fight with a moderator. Just wanted to tell you I disagree with your choice.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Your "answer" was just code style advice and didn't address any potential sources of the problem. The closest you came to answering the question was saying "try and print it to see", which is not enough to be an "answer", and if posted as a comment would almost certainly be flagged "not constructive".

Comment: The "try and print to see" was in the goal to make the OP realize with his code, everything is fine. The answer was that, at least in what he showed us, nothing is wrong (which is the case). And for sure, I gave some code advices that were obviously un-conventional. Still disagree.